# C++ Define iterator for map with template

Tags: c++, iterator

I am trying to write a function to extract keys from map using template to be more generic. Been getting "expected ';' before iter" in the declaration of iterator then "'iter' is not declared in this scope.  Please help.  Here are listing of the function.

```
template<typename TK, typename TV>
std::vector<TK> extract_map_keys(std::map<TK, TV> const& input_map)
{
  std::vector<TK> retval;
  map< TK, TV >::iterator iter; // <-- first ERROR
  for ( iter = input_map.begin(); iter != input_map.end(); iter ++) { // <-- second ERROR
    retval.push_back(iter->first);
  }
  return retval;
}
```

Comment: `typename map< TK, TV >::iterator`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Try for( auto... It is cleaner.

Comment: @ZDF /OT Did you ever consider to change your avatar in [this direction](http://xn--mainzelmnnchen-dib.com/die-mainzelmaennchen-der-schlaue-det/)? ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I guess I'll have to learn German. All I need is an eternity. :o)

Comment: @ZDF The "Mainzelmännchen" are popular here and thoroughly coupled to the ZDF ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Aaa, got it! :o)

Comment: @ZDF "Det" is the _smart guy._

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Of course he's the smart one: he's the only one wearing glasses! Funny guys.